# Merge all the respones to a single observable from a forEach?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to make REST API calls for each element in an array. What is the most efficient way to gather it in a single Observable?
The response from the server is an array of Objects.
I need only one array not array of array of objects. Because it returns that.
Any ideas?

My current method is:

```
  getDocumentsByGroupId() {
    this.form.formGroups.forEach(group =>
      this.documentService.findApprovedDocumentsUsingGET(this.possibility.DOCUMENT_FORM_GROUP, group.id.toString(), 'body', false, false)
        .subscribe(documents => this.documentList.push(documents)));
  }
```

Comment: You can use forkjoin https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

Comment: So you make multiple requests where each returns an array of objects and you want to merge all responses from all arrays into a single array of objects?

Answer (score 1):

Use `forkJoin` if you want to subscribe to multiple observables in parallel.

```
getDocumentsByGroupId() {
  // create an array of observables - won't be run until subscribe is called
  const observables = this.form.formGroups
    .map(group => this.mapGroupToObservable(group));

  forkJoin(observables).subscribe(documents => {
    // documents will be an array of all the responses
    console.log(documents);
    // [ ... ]
  });
}

private mapGroupToObservable(group) {
  return this.documentService
   .findApprovedDocumentsUsingGET(this.possibility.DOCUMENT_FORM_GROUP,
     group.id.toString(), 'body', false, false)
}
```

`forkJoin` will run all of the observables in parallel, and call your subscribe callback when the last one comes back.

I have split your code up to keep the setup clean for the purposes of an easier to understand answer.

I would normally type the functions and variables too, but I wasn't sure of your types.

### Flattening the response objects

If you want to convert your array of arrays into a flat array you can either use `.flat()` or `.reduce()`.

**flat**

No IE support - polyfill required

```
const flattened = documents.flat();
```

**reduce**

```
const flattened = documents.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
```

The reduce example is directly lifted from the [MDN docs for flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)